# jquery margin top

Tags: jquery, margin

I have margin-top defined in the css for the page and I've tried margin-top, marginTop, '250', '250px' and the margin continues to be non-existent when I try to alter it.  Any ideas?

```
$("#content-bottom-left").css({'margin-top':'250px'});
```

The full code is in this [jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/P4MCh/)

Comment: I don't it, what are you trying? When I hover bottom left and add some margin, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/P4MCh/1/

Comment: Regarding your usage of jsFiddle:  You would post your JS in the JavaScript box, insert the `body`'s inner HTML **without** the `html` or `body` tags, leave out the `head` section, and include jQuery in the left pane.  http://jsfiddle.net/P4MCh/3/

Comment: @Sparky672 - Thanks, I was wondering how to do that.  Much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are wrapping your `<img>` in a `span` which is an inline element and doesn't respect block element stuff like margin-*

http://jsfiddle.net/wE5n7/1/

One solution is to change the wrappers to div and use float:left on each